# nginx redirect proxy requests http to https get to many redirections message

Tags: nginx, https, gunicorn

in my nginx server i would to redirect all http incoming request to https.
I use gunicorn and i set as / location a proxy 127.0.0.1:8080
Part of my nginx.conf configuration file is:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443 default ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate  /var/www/web/core/mycert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /var/www/web/core/mykey.key;
    server_name  ~^(?<subdomain>\w+)\.mydomain\.io$;
    root         /var/www;


    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;


    # Load configuration files for the default server block.
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

    location /static/ {
    alias /var/www/web/core/frontend/static/;
    }       

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        proxy_set_header  X-DTS-SCHEMA $subdomain;
    }
```

but when i try to open the http version of my page i get "Error to many redirections"
I also tried to add in my proxy directives:

```
proxy_redirect http:// https://;
```

but nothing happens.

How can i redirect my proxy request to https everytime?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a big mistake in your code, you can't do this like you did:

```
return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
```

If you wish to use like that, you should split the http and https server. When you read your file, you just redirect each time you arrive on the vhost, that's causing the too many redirection.

You could also put a condition on the return to not execute if you already are in https...